# jQuery: append message disappears after showing up

Tags: jquery

My `queue.html` looks like

```
<div class="queue">
    <div class="player_controls">
        <button id="previous" class="btn btn-large navigator-button navigator-icons">
            <i class="icon-backward icon-large"></i>
        </button>
        <button id="play" class="btn btn-large navigator-button navigator-icons">
            <i class="icon-play icon-large"></i>
        </button>
        <button id="next" class="btn btn-large navigator-button navigator-icons">
            <i class="icon-forward icon-large"></i>
        </button>
        <button id="shuffle" class="btn btn-large navigator-button navigator-icons">
            <i class="icon-random icon-large"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="queue_list">
        <!--p>your localStorage data will be displayed here</p-->
        <div class="queue_item hide-item">
            <img class="thumbnail" />
            <p class="title"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my `jQuery` function looks like

```
$(function(){
    $('#queue').click(function(){
        $("#feature").load("templates/queue.html");
        var template = $('.queue_item').clone();
        if (localStorage['queue'] != null ) {
            $('.queue_list').append('<p>You have not added any video to the queue yet</p>');
        } else {
            var queue_list = JSON.parse(localStorage['queue']);
            for (var i = 0; i < queue_list.length; i++) {
                console.log(queue_list[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#play', function(){
        bootstrap_alert.success('will play video now');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#previous', function(){
        bootstrap_alert.success('will play previous video now');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#next', function(){
        bootstrap_alert.success('will play next video now');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#shuffle', function(){
        bootstrap_alert.success('will shuffle videos now');
    });
});
```

the `CSS` looks like

```
.hide-item {
    display: none;
}

.view-item {
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

As soon as I click on `Queue` button, the above `jQuery` function fires up and it displays `html` as `You have not added any video to the queue yet` and disappears quickly.

Why doesn't it stays on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess and say you are appending to a `.queue_list` element that is replaced with the `load()` function.

Try doing the appending in the callback when the new content is loaded :

```
$('#queue').click(function() {
    $("#feature").load("templates/queue.html", function() { //callback
        var template = $('.queue_item').clone();
        if (localStorage['queue'] != null) {
            $('.queue_list').append('<p>You have not added any video to the queue yet</p>');
        } else {
            var queue_list = JSON.parse(localStorage['queue']);
            for (var i = 0; i < queue_list.length; i++) {
                console.log(queue_list[i]);
            }
        }
    });

});​
```

Comment: this is it!, thank you @adeneo, what is the difference between these approach, like my call was in sequence, but was not working

Comment: `load()` uses an ajax `GET` request to load the content, and ajax is asynchronous so it loads the content in the background while your script keeps on going. As such the content was'nt loaded into your site when you where doing the appending so you where in fact appending to an element that was removed when the `load()` was completed a little while later and the message would of course dissapear.

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that you are using buttons. Did you put them inside a form?
If you did, the browser will postback your page and refresh you page. The page will go back to its original state.